# Assign large value to np.array

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

i try to replace all the 0 value inside the array with 1.0/875713. But my code did not work, so just wondering is this due to type size limitation and how to solve this problem?

```
value = 1.0/875713
print(value)
arr = np.array([1,2,3,0,3,0,0,0,2,3,4,5])
arr[arr == 0] = value
print(arr)
```

```
1.14192663578e-06
[1 2 3 0 3 0 0 0 2 3 4 5]
```

Expecting results

```
[1 2 3 1.14192663578e-06 3 1.14192663578e-06 1.14192663578e-06 1.14192663578e-06 2 3 4 5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy array has a type. You can learn more in [docs](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html)

In your code, if you type `arr.dtype`, the result will be `dtype('int32')`

To reach your goal, you should run `arr = arr.astype('float32')` before running `arr[arr == 0] = value`, then you will get the expected output.